How does DS18B20 temperature sensor get the temperature?
I’m trying to understand how the DS18B20 temperature sensors works. Is there a way to know whether it uses a diode or thermistor to calculate the temperature? I couldn’t find anything on the data sheet.

Not related to the sensing technology, but good to know if you use those sensors: if you power it through the separate power line, do not leave the power on constantly. Only power it on when you are going to measure the temperature and then cut the power. They have a problem with internal self heating if left with power.

The 20-year-old patent has expired on the Dallas Semiconductor (DS) design of the DS1820 series and the DS18B20.  There is no thermistor involved. It measures T from voltage not the inverse function of Resistance.
It uses the Vbe absolute and relative changes with an oscillator to count an interval that creates a 2-byte value.  From this, conversion values are digitally stored into NVM with a 10 yr life.


https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/1244260/MAXIM/DS18B20.html
https://patents.google.com/patent/US6215635B1/en
I'm glad you didn't ask how they designed the calibration process. ;)

I'll bite. How did they design the calibration process? Based on what I understand from the patent, the answer is they didn't. "Since each error has its own characteristics with respect to operating temperature and voltage, mechanical stress, and shift in time, the total error cannot be easily trimmed out using one or more calibrations. "

Each part has a unique Look-up table and Serial number based on the voltages of Vbe with CC at two different temperatures like 25'C<>50'C using a mini styrofoam SMD R heaters over case so temperature shifts in a couple of seconds sensed by SMT calibrated sensor on 2oz FPC inside foam with a servo loop. Then uploaded fused data for the sensed data to correct for the 10 mV/&deg C output and 0V at 0'C... I have calibrated +/-50 ppm Xtals into 1 ppm error over 100' C using a counter and 2 temps. 40-70'C using 3rd order equations.  FWIW just a guess @Mast

using back to back cases of sensors in a test jig, one calibrated and the other DUT. micro oven test and calibrate DUT then upload error corrections to flash mem.

The data sheet refers to an application note how to deal with bandgap-based digital sensors.
So it likely uses a silicon bandgap temperature sensor. Which means the bandgap is either a diode or base-emitter junction of a BJT.
However, since it is an internal function of the 1-wire digital thermometer, how it internally gets the result is not something that needs to be aware of when simply asking the chip to return a temperature value.

From Maxim Application Note 4377 Comparison of the DS18B20 and DS18S20 1-
Wire® Digital Thermometers

How the Devices Work:
The DS18B20 and DS18S20 both use the same base design. Temperature measurements are made using two bandgap-generated voltage sources. One of the voltage sources has a high-temperature coefficient and changes deterministically across temperature. The other voltage source has a low temperature coefficient and does not change across temperature. An analog-to-digital converter (ADC) converts the difference between these two voltages to a digital value, representing the temperature of the device. The resolution of the temperature conversion can be selected from 9 to 12 bits.

